# Magnetic moment and angular momentum of electron

Tags: electromagnetism, angular-momentum, electrons, magnetic-moment

I recently got to know about something really interesting.
These are as follows:

1: The magnetic moment of an electron is, $\cfrac{ev}{2πr}$, where $e$ is the charge of the electron, $v$ is its velocity, and $r$ is the radius of the orbit it revolves.

2: The direction of the magnetic moment of the electron is anti-parallel to the direction of angular momentum.

3: The ratio $\cfrac ML$, where M is the magnetic moment, and L is the angular momentum, is constant $\cfrac e{2m}$.

Are these facts somewhat or in some way related to the spin quantum number?

Comment: Your statement 1 is wrong. It should be: The magnetic moment of an electron is $\cfrac{ev}{2\pi r}\cdot\pi r^2$

Comment: @ThomasFritsch Yeah $\frac{ev}{2 \pi r}$ is just $I$. Charge times freq.

Comment: While nothing you listed is relativistic, the particular values for L and M take on discrete values based on quantum effects in the bohr model. The orbits are integer numbers of wavelengths of the electron’s debroglie matter-wave. In that sense, yes quantum 

Comment: Spin doesnt affect magnetic dipole moment. Magnetic dipole is only from the moving charge making a magnetic field. The charge orbiting. But something revolving and spinning does have different *angular momentum* than if not spinning

Comment: Im pretty sure (~90% certain) that this is correct: Spin doesn’t affect magnetic dipole moment. Magnetic dipole is only from the moving charge making a magnetic field. The charge orbiting. But something revolving and spinning does have different **angular** momentum than if not spinning

Answer (score 2):

What you described is called the [gyromagnetic ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gyromagnetic_ratio)
between magnetic moment ($M$) and orbital angular momentum ($L$)
of the electron
$$\gamma_l=\frac{M}{L}=\frac{e}{2m}$$
where $e$ and $m$ are charge and mass of the electron.

However this relation holds only for the [*orbital* angular momentum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_momentum#Orbital_angular_momentum_in_three_dimensions).
The corresponding relation for the [*spin* angular momentum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_(physics)) ($S$)
experimentally turned out to be
$$\gamma_s=\frac{M}{S}=\frac{e}{m}$$
Notably, this ratio is not the same, but double of the $\gamma_l$ above.

Comment: Hi would you look at my answer and see where the mistake is. Even just taking $M=\frac{ev}{2\pi r}$ as given it isnt working out

Comment: Look up the definition of the magnetic moment of a current loop.

Comment: Ok I had remembered magnetic dipole wrong. And yes M in the question was wrong (is =freq x e x area). Just got e/m when i fixed it thanks.

Comment: But I didnt get what spin actually is based on your answer. Can you please elaborate what spin is based on magnetic moment and angular momentum

Comment: When an electron goes around a nucleus, it travels a certain distance “in a circle” which gives angular velocity and hence angular momentum. It is also “spinning” as it goes, so the angular momentum is double that much, spin +1/2. Or if it is spinning with the opposite clockwiseness as the orbit, that’s spin -1/2. I dont know if electrons would do that with negative spin here though or thats only other particles. Very clear anawer Thomas 

Comment: But I saw somewhere on youtube where the person said that spinning should not be compared to actual rotation of electron. Its not the same.

Comment: @SamyakMarathe Which video? What exactly did this person say?
I didn't say, spin actually is rotation of the electron around itself. (Indeed this is a metaphor used only in pop science.) But nevertheless spin angular momentum and spin magnetic moment can be measured experimentally, and then $\gamma_s$ can be calculated from the measured values.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no. While nothing you listed is relativistic, L and M will take on only discrete values based on quantum effects in the bohr model. The orbits are integer numbers of wavelengths of the electron’s debroglie matter-wave. In that sense, yes quantum.

But the formulae considered are all classical Maxwell stuff. The field for the dipole comes from the classical (non-relativistic) Bio-savart Law for a point charge:

$$\vec{B} = \frac {\mu_0 q \vec{v} \times \vec{r}}{4 \pi |r|^2}, \text{ } q=e<0$$

(The following article is easy and quick to pan through, *see **Moving Charges Create Magnetic Fields**:* https://www.school-for-champions.com/science/magnetic_field_moving_charges.htm )

This is how the magnetic field is created. $\vec{v} \times \vec{r}$ by the right-hand rule points a direction we know define as up, making $\vec{B}$ down due to $q<0$.

The field maximum is inside the electron loop on the plane of orbit. A closed-current loop is commonly referred to as a magnetic dipole with $IA$ its magnetic dipole moment $\vec{M}$, direction down as of $\vec{B}$, where $A$ is enclosed area, and current $I=\tfrac{dq}{dt}=fe$ , frequency times charge (the electron’s charge times how many times the electron passes per unit time). $\implies M = feA$:

$$M = feA = (\tfrac{v}{2 \pi r})e(\pi r^2) = \tfrac{1}{2} evr$$

$$\vec{L}= I \vec{\omega} = (m|r|^2) (\vec{v} \times  \tfrac{\vec{r}}{|r|^2})=m\vec{v} \times \vec{r}$$

Where $\vec{L}$ points up by $v \times r$ as noted in the question.

$$\implies \frac{M}{L} = \frac{e}{2m}<0$$

Comment: The equation $M=\frac{ev}{2\pi r}$ cannot be correct.
Its right-hand side has the dimension of a current, but not of a magnetic moment.

Comment: What is "a" in your last formula?

Comment: @nasu Area a = pi r^2. Just cuz it was there

Comment: @nasu yes I thought I knew mag dipole but remembered wrong. That fixed it thanks  

Comment: Also kindve cool i got and noticed area, as it is in the definition of magnetic dipole (although not as good that i had that definition completely wrong  ). Anyway thanks again. Gnight

Comment: The part where you calculate M, is wring. It should by evr/2. May be you missed 2.

Comment: @SamyakMarathe Youre right!  Thanks

Comment: @SamyakMarathe I could claim I was accounting for the spin’s contribution to angular momentum (which doubles it, as described in the other answer), but no.. I just made a mistake lol

Comment: Its ok, but look at this way. Consider it a beginning of quantum mechanics and my question was that if the spin quantum number related to the magnetic moment of electron which I studied in physics class.